# Make scrollbars visible on iOS?

Tags: css, ios

I need scrollbars to be visible when a div has the `overflow` set to `auto` on mobile Safari and Chrome. Using `::-webkit-scrollbar` in CSS works on desktop but not mobile.

https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/wvdrzMe

The question has been asked already but the accepted answer doesn't work: [Make scrollbar visible in mobile browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22907777/make-scrollbar-visible-in-mobile-browsers)

Comment: This is not exactly the answer but if you want to give indication that there is more content  and user can scroll down then you can try this  https://stackoverflow.com/q/70131020/15273968

Comment: [Codepen](http://www.codepen.io) is using it's own JS scrollbar. There are good opensource JS scrollbars available like. Https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512885/11974339 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/17276376/11974339.